# why export and import error in node.js 9?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning the javascript not long. I make two files like bellow.
app.js:

```
import * as  Conf from './conf'
console.log(Conf.a)
```

conf.js:

```
export let a = 1
```

And i just run the command in console:

```
node app.js
```

It was err. The err msg:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * 
as Conf from './conf'

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Can anyone tell me why? And what is about the javascript and babel and so on. I am not so familiar about the concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a comity that each year promote a new javascript norm that are called ECMA 2015 (ES6), ECMA 2016 (ES7), ECMA 2017 (ES8) ...

Each norm describe the functionality javascript must have.

It exists multiple javascript engines in the market:

- V8 from google (and node)
- Chakra from microsoft
- Rhino from mozilla

and so on

Theses engines try to keep up to the norm, but are not 100% compliant.

[here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) you can see a compatibility table about the engines and ES6.

[image]

---

The problem you can imagine now, is "Why if I want to use the brand new ES8 right away?". There is two answer:  Either you wait for node.js to implement it, either you use a **transpiler** like **Babel**.

Babel takes the code you do and transpile it into an older norm (ES5) which is fully compatible with node.js.

For example, you want to use `import` which is an ES6 feature. Babel gonna transform your `import` into `require` so node.js can execute it.

It's very usefull and powerfull to use a transpiler so you an use right away the last feature that are improving the productivity of your developper team.

---

Like @Tuan Anh Tran said, you can use a flag to say to node.js to run it's experimental features, which represent the features it's implementing right now *(not particulary safe so for production)*.

---

[Here](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) is an article about ES6 features.

[Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ecmascript-2016-es7-features-86903c5cab70) is an article about ES7 features.

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/es8-was-released-and-here-are-its-main-new-features-ee9c394adf66) about ES8 features.

Comment: To the point. I just want to ask you one question though. When we use `babel` we put that in `devDependencies`. How babel transpiles es6 in prod env. Am I missing something?

Comment: You create the code. You transpile it. You run it. [Here](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/setup-babel/) is a tutorial about how to set up a babel environment. I recommand you to look for the keywords Grunt + Babel when doing a research on howto set up your project :)

Answer (score 2):

`import` is ESM keyword and it's in experimental. See nodejs [documentation on esm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

If you really want to use it, you can either use babel or run your app with `--experimental-modules` flag and name your file `.mjs` extension

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Babel or another transpiler to use ES6 import/export in NodeJS.

Babel installation you can find here: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Also you can use NodeJS module loading system. 
Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

In your case:

app.js

```
var conf = require('./conf');
console.log(conf);
```

conf.js

```
let a = 1;
module.exports = a;
```

Or

app.js

```
var conf = require('./conf');
console.log(conf.a);
```

conf.js

```
let a = 1;
exports.a = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already pointed out, the keywords `import` and `export` are experimental. 
That's why I'd suggest using `require()`:

Your **app.js**:

```
let conf = require("./conf");
console.log(conf.a);
```

Your **conf.js**:

```
let a = 1;
exports.a = a;
```

`node app.js` will then print `1` to the console.